# No constructor called when calling function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

`MyType` has both a copy and a move ctor defined. When executing the following snippet (after compiling with VS2015) :

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& o) {
    // do something with o
}

int main() {
    MyType o{ 1, 2, 3 };
    f(o); // call of copy-constructor expected
    f(std::move(o)); // call of move-constructor expected
}
```

I would have expected the copy constructor to be called after the first call of `f` and the move constructor after the second call of `f`. But no constructor actually did get called in any case. I suspect this behavior to be a compiler optimization, but am not sure about portability or compliance with the standard.

Comment: Would you expect `MyType& r = o` to invoke the copy constructor?

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/imyPZhbgkL0iCbUI

Comment: @Barry: No, of course not. I missed the point that T&& gets deduced to T& in a template. But concerning the second call `f(std::move(o))`, I still can't figure how the the object in f can reference another object that's been moved-from at the calling site.

Comment: And how exactly is this temporary object constructed then, if not by invoking  the move ctor (which I actually defined, see my question) ?

Comment: ok, I was wrong. `std::move` do not do any move. It only converts to rvalue reference. Move constructors are called typically when objects are initialized. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor. If you change to `void f(T o)` it will be called for the second call

Comment: Right, so the interesting question is still: why isn't  the move ctor invoked in the case of  `template<typename T>(T&& o)` ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Yow have only calls by references because you have only references - no object initialization

Comment: @Angle.Bracket passing by reference does not construct any objects ; the reference is bound to the argument

Comment: @Angle.Bracket To check if something is a compiler optimization or not, you can use compiler explorer and not define the function you want to check. Compiler cannot optimize if it cannot see the implementation. E.g https://godbolt.org/g/dp9wao
You don't have to understand the assembly completely. Just look at the `call` statements to know what is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both calls are by reference - the first by a *lvalue* reference and second by and *rvalue* reference. `T&&` works with both and is called [*forward reference*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) ([N4164](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4164.pdf)). Scott Meyers called them [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and are especially useful as template parameters and as `auto&&`.

`std::move` is used to *indicate* ownership transfer but do not actually do any move. Its effect is of a static_cast to rvalue reference.

So you have:

```
void f(MyType& ) {}
void f(MyType&& ) {}
...
f(o);                         // calls void f(MyType& )
f(static_cast<MyType&&>(o));  // calls void f(MyType&& )
```

Move constructors are typically called when objects are initialized.

> [Move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) cppreference.com
>
> The move constructor is called whenever selected by overload
>   resolution, which typically occurs when an object is initialized (by
>   direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from rvalue (xvalue or
>   prvalue) (until C++17)xvalue (since C++17) of the same type, including
>
> - initialization: `T a = std::move(b);` or `T a(std::move(b));`, where b is of type T;
> - function argument passing: `f(std::move(a));`, where a is of type T and f is `void f(T t);`
> - function return: `return a;` inside a function such as `T f()`, where a is of type T which has a move constructor.

If you change `f` to `void f(T o)` the copy constructor will be called for the first call and the move constructor for the second.

---

[Universal vs Forwarding References in C++](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2016/09/17/universal-vs-forwarding-references-in-cpp)

Comment: The term is forwarding reference.

Comment: Or rather [forwarding reference](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4164.pdf) (note *3.1: Q&A/Why not universal reference*).

Comment: I see that o in f references o in main in the first case. But what is o referencing in the second case, when the argument in main is now moved-from ?

Comment: `std::move` makes it an rvalue reference (actually an xvalue but still equivalent). And `std::forward` could be used in templates to achieve perfect forwarding

Comment: @A.A : see my comment to the question

Comment: I see your point, but you seem to have modified the original question by replacing a template function with a forwarding/universal-reference parameter with two overloads of a non-template function of which one is accepting a reference and the other an rvalue-reference. The question is still: why is the move ctor *not* invoked in the second call of the original scenario ?

Comment: Your template produces these two functions when called with `o` and with `std::move(o)`. o binds to T& and move(o) to T&& - both references. No new objects no constructors called. And nothing is moved.

Comment: Look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor - "function argument passing: f(std::move(a));, where a is of type T and f is void f(T t); " -- T by-value and needs initialization